# How to get grouped items using groupby method

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','A','B','B','B'], 'col2':['C','D','D','D','C','C'], 'col3':[.1,.2,.4,.6,.8,1]})
```

Then I group two columns as follows:

```
g = df.groupby(['col2','col1'])
```

And then I would like to get a list of all groups' name (e.g. something like `g.groupnames()`) and:

```
g.get_group('D','A')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
g.groups.keys()
```

[('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'A'), ('D', 'B')]

```
g.groups[('D','A')]
```

[1, 2]

If you want to use g.get_group(), you need to pass it a tuple, not two strings:

```
g.get_group(('D','A'))
```